# Optimization (NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR) not behaving properly on Tabular in Power BI Premium

Tags: powerbi, ssas, mdx, tabular, ssas-tabular

I noticed that Microsoft is continuing to improve the MDX query language on Power BI.  Eg. they have features called "MDX Fusion" that was released relatively recently.  While Power BI also has the DAX queries, the MDX ones are still very important for data analysis, and they are used in various places, like Microsoft Excel.

... MDX is also used for "import" mode queries when pulling data into Power Query from any olap source (SQL Analysis Services or Azure Analysis Services).

Despite the improvements, there are some performance issues in MDX that I'm having trouble with.  I cannot seem to influence the performance of my custom measures, with the help of "**NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR**".  Take the following query for example:

```
WITH 
                            
      MEMBER [Measures].[NewSalesEmployeeId] 
      
      as Iif(IsEmpty([Measures].[Units Sold]), NULL, "000000")

            , NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR=[Sales].[ValUnits]

      SELECT

      {{ 
      [Measures].[Units Sold]
      , 
      [Measures].[NewSalesEmployeeId]
      }}


      ON 0,


      NON EMPTY  

        [Branch].[Branch Code].[Branch Code] *
        [Customer].[Customer Code].[Customer Code] *
        [Product].[Product Type Code].[Product Type Code] *

        [Product].[Descriptor - Species Code].[Descriptor - Species Code] *
        [Product].[Descriptor - Grade Code].[Descriptor - Grade Code] *
        [Product].[Descriptor - Grade Name].[Descriptor - Grade Name] *
        [Product].[Descriptor - Size Name].[Descriptor - Size Name] *
        [Product].[Descriptor - Thick Name].[Descriptor - Thick Name] *

        [Product].[Product Code].[Product Code] *
        [Product].[Length].[Length] *

        [Time].[Fiscal Day Value].[Fiscal Day Value]



        ON 1 FROM ( SELECT [Time].[Time F].[Week].[Y 2022  W 10]  on 0 FROM (SELECT [Branch].[Branch Code].[Branch Code].[B123] on 0 from [Sales Budget and Activity]))
```

This takes far too long.
It clocks in at ~3422 ms in profiler.  See below.

[image]

The use of NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR was a "plan B".  My goal when I introduced the NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR on **[Measures].[NewSalesEmployeeId]** was simply to improve performance.  I only want to evaluate the member **if the units are available** for the tuples in question.

Please note that if I simply remove **[Measures].[NewSalesEmployeeId]** from my query then the it takes only ~80 ms or so.  See below. This is the approximate timeframe I would expect in every permutation of my query.  The final results consist of only about ~1000 rows.  IMHO, There is no reasonable scenario where this query should take ~3422 ms to return ~1000 rows, especially if the only thing I need is a few additional measures (ones that are directly related to "units sold").

[image]

In every case I'm testing with warm cache, on a Power BI model in premium P1.

Is there any hope to get an MDX query working in a way that pays **respect to my NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR**?  Is there any other technique to improve the version of my query that has a custom calculation in my "Measures"?

It is a bit disappointing that the NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR feature seems to be ignored.  That feature always been a low-tech and simple way to improve performance when all else fails.  I do understand that MDX is not the primary language of PBI tabular models, but it is still an important query language nonetheless.  And we need it to be fast.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use DAX for this?  Especicially for "import" mode queries when pulling data into Power Query from any olap source (SQL Analysis Services or Azure Analysis Services)." you should always use DAX when hitting a tabular model.

Comment: I could use DAX.  That is implied, and that is the language used from PBI reports themselves.  But please note that MDX queries seems to be the end result that is generated from the Power Query designer for "import" (when building a query interactively).  So it is natural to "harvest" the MDX and make some tweaks to it rather than starting from scratch with DAX.  Both are pretty important query languages at Microsoft, and I don't see MDX ever being replaced (even if were able to use ANSI SQL against PBI models it would probably still not kill off MDX altogether!)

Comment: Yes.  But the MDX that the designer generates is not suitable for data extracts.  It should only be used to return small aggregations.  It's unfortunate that it is the default experience.

Comment: Do you have a source?  Saying it is not suitable for extracts sounds strange to me, considering that PQ's only mission in life is extraction. ... In any case no tabular model is going to be that suitable for extracts .  My experience is that the in-memory columnstore engine won't retrieve large amounts of wide rows well, especially across several joins.  Regardless of whether you are getting the data out via MDX or DAX, the experience is not going to be great in import mode.  I don't think it is MDX's fault necessarily  (except when certain optimization features are deliberately omitted)

Comment: In order for OLAP sources to be suitable for imports, we have found some workarounds and use them regularly.  We typically just loop over the time dimension, and the organization as well, and then we transmit lots of "bite-sized" MDX queries to the data source.  This allows a considerably large extract/import to run without being cancelled by back-end server operations.  On P1 you can run an import like this for over an hour if you need to (I think 5 hours is the absolute limit).

Comment: If you are taking the approach of harvesting the code behind the scenes, you could build a visual in Power BI and then harvest the DAX. You have conditional logic, so you could build one visual for each branch and then add the IF statement and combine them. DAX can also be used in the same places in Excel where I use MDX. I would much rather support DAX than MDX.

Comment: And David doesn't have to cite a source. He is a Microsoft SSAS expert. He is the source!

Comment: Anyone saying that a query language is "not suitable for extracts" is making an oversimplification.  The query language itself, or even a syntax of the language is just the interface for accessing the data.  It is the data source itself that has to prove itself suitable or not (ie. the query parser, formula engine, storage engine, network protocol, and so on).  If someone thinks DAX is generally fast and MDX is generally slow, for retrieving an *equivalent* result set, then they should have some proof. They should provide corroborating documentation from that crazy ASWL team at Microsoft.